# Seeking alternatives for data replication

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Current setup

SOR is an Oracle system
Reporting is a SQL Server system

A rather large table needs to be copied from Oracle to the SQL box.

99% of the data will not be modified, but new records will be added to the Oracle table.
The data delta will need to be put into the SQL Server.

The data refresh on the SQL Server is to be scheduled for the 2:00AM hour.

I have concerns that the full data pull of 1.2 billion records will take longer than the window will allow.

a solution i was tossing around was to only pull the current months data, deleting the data from the SQL box for the previous 30 days, and pulling only the last 30 days data from the Oracle system.

a HUGE problem with that idea is...  there is no date field to work with *UGH*

Another idea is to add the ROWID field to the SQL Server table, and do full table scan for that value, if it isnt found, then add it.  If found update with new fields.  This feels like a brute force, full table scan for each record (not ideal - IMO)

If anyone has a different idea(s) i would really like to hear them.

Comment: Make a table on the *Oracle* side to keep track of which records have been successfully transferred/updated to the SQL side.  This is a much more efficient way to find the new records in the Oracle table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you could explore

Option 1 - If you can get away with adding an index to your Oracle table

Add a new date column, make it invisible so (near) zero risk of impact to existing application code.  Note: near != zero.

Make the column default SYSDATE to handle inserts automatically, and add a trigger to capture updates as well. Index the column for performance.  If you need deletes as well, then see option 2.

On refresh time, use this column to pick up all row deltas and push to SQL Server.  If index space is an issue, you could null out the column value as you push the data across so that the index only holds untransferred data.

Important note: You need to manage serialization carefully so that you don't miss an uncommitted transaction. A common approach is lock table, open cursor, commit to release lock, then fetch from cursor to guarantee integrity.  Other strategies are a little more complex and involve looking at oldest active transactions on V$TRANSACTION.

Option 2 - no indexes or extra columns possible

Add an insert/update/delete trigger to capture the operation (I,U,D) and the rowid or primary key of the row concerned plus a sequence number to guarantee ordering of changes into a separate table.  (Aka a home grown materialized view log).

Then at refresh time, use this to apply the changes to the remote SQL Server table in the order they were applied on the Oracle table.  You still pay the trigger cost but no additional indexes/columns on the source table.